# How to auto-resize NSWindow based on auto layout contentView's minimum size

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, autolayout

At the moment the behaviour of my app allows me to called this extra function I wrote that hacks resizes the window to fittingSize.

```
- (void)fitToMinimumSize
{
    NSRect frame = [self frame];
    frame.size = [[self contentView] fittingSize];
    int originalHeight = [self frame].size.height;
    int diff = originalHeight - frame.size.height;
    frame.origin.y += diff;
    [self setFrame:frame display:YES];
}
```

But can I automate this behaviour through some built in auto layout code so that the window is always the size of the minimum of it's contentView instead of this almighty hack?

Edit: I've found out I can check [[self contentView] fittingSize], but how can I observe this incase it changes, or should I be triggering it myself?

Comment: Please mind that using [Autolayout](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/UserExperience/RNAutomaticLayout/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010631) constraints is not the same as using autoresizing masks..

Answer (score 1):

Normally, everything should already be 'automatic' if your layout is fully and unambiguously determined by `NSConstraint`'s set on your window's content view and its children.

In your case I'd try installing a height and a width constraints on the content view with sufficiently small dimensions (maybe even zero), but with priority lower than the 'content compression resistance priority' set on your subviews. To have everything working properly, you may have to play with constraint priorities and/or install additional constraints on the content view's children.

This should work without any other code, as long as your subviews are constrained to resist collapsing to zero. I'd also think that in this case the window should not be user-resizeable.